# Multi-tenant multi-region SaaS with per-customer subdomain

Tags: aws, software-as-a-service, multitenancy

I am trying to figure out how to design SaaS system that offers subdomain per customer (e.g. `<customer>.example.com`), where each customer is on specific region.

Due to compliance and regulation, some customers must have all data in specific regions. There are two deployments of existing system (US and EU) with different domains. System is available only on these domains and customer must know on which system they are in order to access it.

Now, I want to have domains in form `<customer-name>.example.com` and have it automatically use deployment in appropriate region.

Two approaches come to mind:

1. have single onboarding endpoint and during onboarding contact services in appropriate region, including configuring DNS to point subdomain to services in appropriate region.
2. have `*.example.com` DNS record point to global proxy that knows how to route requests to appropriate region based on `*` part of the URL by checking where the customer should go.

Cloud provider is AWS, Route53 for DNS management and EKS is used. Current deployments are completely separated (except for CI, monitoring and such). I am looking for solution to utilise managed services as much as possible to reduce implementation time and maintenance overhead.

Option #1 is not ideal as it requires dynamically setting DNS records and potentially exposes clients names by enumerating existing DNS records.

Option #2 introduces additional latency and potential compliance problems (in which region is proxy hosted?).

Are there any other options that I am not seeing? Are there some useful articles or resources on this topic?

Comment: Is there a reason why everything needs to be a subdomain of `example.com` as opposed to have two domains or multiple levels of subdomains?

Comment: Mostly marketing and making it easier for users to navigate to name.example.com instead of having to know if it is name.us.example.com or name.eu.example.com, no technical reason, but it is one of the requirements.

Comment: Well, if `name` is globally unique and it cannot be any of your first subdomains (meaning you can't have a name of `us`, for example), you could have a mapping in both the US and EU regions that just says where each tenant is. You wouldn't be storing any customer data in the wrong data center, just system configuration in both.

Comment: @ThomasOwens sometimes a simple solution like that is much better!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you explore the DNS routing, and confirm that would work for your scenario before considering a proxy. You've already enumerated some possible upside of doing so, but I think there are more depending on your use case:

1. You leave routing at the edge, where it can massively scale (separation of concerns)
2. Route 53 subdomains are tenant-specific, which could help in certain scenarios - (debugging, disabling, observability)
3. You don't have a compute proxy which could be a regional point of failure (reliability)
4. As you said - compliance. Traffic is arriving in the appropriate region, lowering compliance footprint
5. Avoid possible cross-region data transfer costs (depends on how routing works)
6. Potential for shifting routing policies over time transparently

As for the negative you listed, making customer names discoverable through DNS listing. If that is a concern, I'd consider using the same pattern .example.com, but simply replace customer-name with an random value, especially if you don't see any customer value in a friendly URL. So instead of big-fintech-company.example.com, you have ds78weh97.example.com.

My team - the AWS SaaS Factory - has an [EKS SaaS Reference Architecture](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-saas-factory-eks-reference-architecture) that includes (at least in the current version) subdomain routing in Route 53. It does NOT do multi-region routing, but perhaps it could be useful for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on the proposed solution in [my comment on the question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/444704/multi-tenant-multi-region-saas-with-per-customer-subdomain?noredirect=1#comment977975_444704).

If the `name` is globally unique and you enforce constraints that `name` is not any of your subdomains, you could have a mapping in each of your regions that maps the `name` (of your tenant) to a region or data center. This would map the name to a particular data center that hosts the data. When a user accesses `name.example.com`, it would look up and redirect to `name.us.example.com` or `name.eu.example.com` or potentially even a future `name.apac.example.com` or `name.mena.example.com`. You would need to prevent `name` from being one of your regions, so `eu` or `us` would not be valid tenant names.

Depending on your requirements and implementation details, you may not even need to redirect. Although redirecting to the appropriate data center is one option, you could end up hosting your application code in all your regions, directing your users to the closest region (perhaps based on IP geolocation), and querying data from data stores (such as databases and file stores) that live in a particular region. Users may never see your region-specific URLs.

You have some decisions about replication. Do you replicate your tenant identification data across all your regions and redirect users to the closest one? Do you direct everyone to a central data store and make queries to regions? Do you look up and redirect, but give users the option to go directly to `name.region.example.com`?